# Remove layers from a group and update LayerSwitcher with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, group-layer, add-ons

I have a layer group in OpenLayers that initializes empty. This group is added in a layer switcher

```
var group_search = new ol.layer.Group({
 title: 'Search',
 fold: 'open',
 layers: []
});
map.addLayer(group_search)
var toc = document.getElementById('layers');
ol.control.LayerSwitcher.renderPanel(map, toc, { reverse: false });
```

According to a search results - layers are added into this empty group.

```
group_search.getLayers().push(my_layer)
```

The group does not update automatically, you need to uncheck and check again to show the layers in the group.

At a certain point, when I perform a new search, I need to delete the layers from the group, update the layer switcher, and this is not happening automatically. How should I do?

I already tried these codes below, but they didn't work.

```
group_search.getLayers().getArray().forEach(function (layer) {
    group_search.getLayers().remove(layer);
})

group_search.getLayers().clear();
```

Comment: Try calling `renderPanel` again after adding or removing a layer https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher#renderpanel